# Load div for ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

This has been asked before and I did look around, tried many methods but it does not execute. Only an `alert` function seems to work. I am trying to load a small div on `success:` after executing my `POST` in ajax. Here is my code:

```
$("#send").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'actions/update.php',
            data: $('#content').serialize(),
            success: function() {
          $(this).html('<div id="status">Saved!</div>');
          }
          });

        });

      $('#status').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
```

My CSS to this Div:

```
#status {
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
z-index:100000;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
border-radius:150px;
font-size:30px;
line-height:150px;
font-weight:700;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
cursor:default; }
```

Could I be causing conflict somewhere? Is this because `e.preventDefault();` Any help or link would be appreciated!

Comment: Get it out of the `success:` object and use the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#send").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
          var that = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'actions/update.php',
            data: $('#content').serialize(),
            success: function() {
          that.html('<div id="status">Saved!</div>');

          $('#status').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
          }
          });

        });
```

The issue here is that `this` is not what you think it is inisde the callback. Try the above

Edit:
In response to your comment:

The text is overwritten by the new `div`. One way to get around that is to insert the new div into a child element of the original element instead. To get the fading effect you have to put that into the callback as well. Otherwise it will execute before the ajax call returns. This is because ajax calls are asynchronous and the rest of the JavaScript code will continue to execute while you're waiting for the server to return the data

Edit2:
I am not sure what type of element you're clicking, but there are two approaches here:

1) Add a child element into the clicked element
ex: `<a #id="send"><div id=someElement></div></a>`

2) Add an element next to the clicked element and target that with the new div

Comment: Thank you, This seems to do the trick, however, the text in the submit button seems to disappear, I would expect this to have something to do with  `$("#send").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you again, your responses have been of great assistance. I will work around getting the new div into a child element, have you got any links that can help educate more so on this topic? Much appreciate.

Comment: Just put an element with an id (ex:someElement) inside the clicked element and do something like this that.find("#someElement").html("<div id="status">Saved!</div>"); instead of the current line

Comment: I'm soo sorry man and hate to do this to you, my English is not the best, but can you elaborate on putting an element with an id (ex:someElement) inside the clicked element?

Answer (score 2):

Inside an $.ajax callback the context(`this`) is by default the jqXHR object returned by $.ajax.
However you can use the context property in the configuration object for the $.ajax method to set what ever you want it to be. e.g.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'actions/update.php',
    data: $('#content').serialize(),
    context: this, //<----
    success: function() {
      $(this).html('<div id="status">Saved!</div>');
    }
  });
```

This will set the context in all callbacks to the one in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#send").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'actions/update.php',
        data: $('#content').serialize(),
    }).done(function() {
        $('#status').html('Saved!');
    });
$('#status').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
<div id='status'></div>
```

Comment: @DevishOne - I do not know who downvoted you, but I would say you answer is just fine.

Comment: I think they changed their mind. LOL... but, thanks.